# Android Edit text Masking

Tags: java, android

I want to add masking .. 
like 00000-0000000-0

```
etusercnic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                String str = s.toString();
                if (s.length() == 5 || s.length() == 13) {
                    str += "-";
                    etusercnic.setText(str);
                    etusercnic.setSelection(str.length());
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

It works perfectly,when first time i entered the value, but when i remove any digit it placed - sign. so what can i do..

Comment: Fahad learn to [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on stack over flow. If it worked for you, if it didn't work then comment with the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you're masking it for CNIC :D

Anyways here is my version of masking, it works perfectly:

```
        etusercnic.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); 
        etusercnic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int len = 0;
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String val = etusercnic.getText().toString();
            if((val.length()==5 && len <val.length()) || (val.length()==13 && len<val.length())){
                etusercnic.append("-");
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            String str = etusercnic.getText().toString();
            len = str.length();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

The xml of your Edittext should be something similar to this:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/nic_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/signup_cnic_hint"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#808080"
    android:textSize="15sp" 
     />
```

Comment: etusercnic.append("-"); not working. Result is - 000000000000

Comment: Thanks Your Help.. Sharp Edge

Answer (score 1):

Good luck with your project! The easiest way I know to use a mask on EditText in your Android programs in Android Studio is to use `MaskedEditText` library ([GitHub link](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)).
It's a kind of custom EditText with Watcher that allows you to set a hint with different color (if you want if will be available even when user already started to type), mask and it's very easy to use :-)

It's very easy in your case:

```
compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'

<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
    mask:mask="#####-#######-#"
    android:hint="0000000000000"
    app:keep_hint="true"
    />
```

And that is! Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some help.. i found a way. Correct Answer...Perfect Working. :)

```
 etusercnic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int len = 0;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            String str = etusercnic.getText().toString();
            len = str.length();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                String str = s.toString();

                String val = etusercnic.getText().toString();
                if ((val.length() == 5 && len < val.length()) || (val.length() == 13 && len < val.length())) {
                    str += "-";
                    etusercnic.setText(str);
                    etusercnic.setSelection(str.length());
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```